# La mejor manera de bindear la propiedad de un ViewModel en post

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvvm

Buenas,

La idea es la siguiente:
Tengo un proyecto en ASP.NET 4.6.2 siguiendo el patron MVVM, tengo mi clase ViewModel que representa la pagina y una de las propiedades de ese ViewModel es un objeto que a su vez tiene como propiedad otro objeto. Paso a codigo lo escrito:

```
public class AlumnoViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public List<AlumnoModel> Alumnos { get; set; }
    public AlumnoModel SearchEntity { get; set; }
    public AlumnoModel AddEntity { get; set; }

    public int TurnoId { get; set; }
    public int CarreraId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Carreras { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Turnos { get; set; } 
 }
```

La propiedad `AddEntity` (Que es un AlumnoModel) seria mi POCO que luego va a ser mapeado con Automapper a su clase de dominio para persistencia.

Muestro como es mi AddEntity:

```
public class AlumnoModel
{
    [Display(Name ="Nombre")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Apellido")]
    public string Apellido { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "N° Legajo")]
    public string Legajo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Dni")]
    public int Dni { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Carrera")]
    public CarreraModel Carrera { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Turno")]
    public TurnoModel Turno { get; set; }
}
```

Casi todas las propiedades de esta clase son fuertemente tipadas excepto dos, que sera Carrera y Turno que son a su vez otros dos POCOs. Muestro uno porque son identicos:

```
public class TurnoModel
{
    public int TurnoId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Turno")]
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
}
```

Entonces la idea es la siguiente: Mi `AddEntity` representa un alumno, ese alumno tiene varias propiedades, también tiene un turno y una carrera, por lo que pueden ver es una relación de 1 a n entre la tabla Turnos, Carrera con Alumnos.

Ahora bien, la idea es que al querer guardar un Alumno desde la capa de presentación a mi base de datos mi `AddEntity` pasa al controlador con todos sus datos MENOS aquellos que son objetos complejos. El usuario elige un turno y una carrera a través de un `@Html.DropDownListFor` paso a mostrar esta parte de la vista:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AddEntity.Turno)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Turnos, Model.Turnos, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AddEntity.Carrera)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Carreras, Model.Carreras, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
```

Como se ve, estoy creando dos DropDown con las propiedades Carreras y Turnos de mi ViewModel que son dos SelectListItem.

Lo que intente hacer es, por medio de jQuery, capturar el valor seleccionado en estos dos DropDown y pasárselo a estas dos propiedades que pasaran por medio de dos `HiddenFor`. Estos son mis Hidden:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AddEntity.Carrera.CarreraId)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AddEntity.Turno.TurnoId)
```

Y acá el jQuery:

```
    if (action === "Save")
    {
        var carreraId = parseInt($("#Carreras option:selected").val());
        var turnoId = parseInt($("#Turnos option:selected").val());

        $("#AddEntity_Turno_TurnoId").val(turnoId);
        $("#AddEntity_Carrera_CarreraId").val(carreraId);
    }
```

La pregunta seria, hay alguna mejor manera de bindear estos datos sin tener que pasar por jQuery para bindearlo? Se que es un tema del DefaultModelBinder. Tendría que crear uno Custom?

Answer (score 0):

Déjame decirte que no estas utilizando/implementando el patrón MVVM. Posiblemente haya confusión porque en ASP.NET MVC utiliza el nombre de "ViewModel", pero no es lo mismo que el ViewModel del patrón MVVM, es una simple clase POCO cuyo único cometido es ser la representación de las propiedades del modelo que quieres mostrar en la vista.

Si tienes un modelo con varias propiedades, pero en la vista solo necesitas unos cuantas propiedades, no todas, creas un "ViewModel" con las propiedades del modelo que vas a necesitar, así no pasas a la vista todo el modelo.

No hay "bindeo" como requiere el patrón MVVM a menos que utilices javascript y frameworks como Knockout para hacer el bindeo con el DOM.

Aunque Razor pueda "bindear" lo que llaman "ViewModel", sigue siendo el patrón MVC ya que el controlador rellena la vista y la manda al navegador, pero una vez en el navegador, a menos que puedas modificar el DOM con JS, no hay forma que la vista actualice esos binding como en MVVM.

Si no quieres usar js (jquery), prueba con Blazor, ya liberaron un preview y con Blazor usas c# en vez de javascript para modificar el DOM.

O utiliza un framework como DotVVM, que implementa el patrón MVVM creando los ViewModels en el servidor con c# y agrega marcaciones html especiales que luego el framework los transforma en kockout, así no usas ni jquery ni javascript.

Como el ViewModel vive en el servidor, puedes hacer la carga de datos directamente de la base de datos y no necesitarías crear una API que se use desde javascript.

Ejemplo usando de ViewModel con DotVVM:

```
public class CalculatorViewModel 
{

    public int Number1 { get; set; }

    public int Number2 { get; set; }

    public int Result { get; set; }

    public void Calculate() 
    {
        Result = Number1 + Number2;
    }
}
```

Ejemplo de la vista con DotVVM:

```
@viewModel DotvvmDemo.CalculatorViewModel, Dotvvm

<p>
  Enter the first number: 
  <dot:TextBox Text="{value: Number1}" />
</p>
<p>
  Enter the second number: 
  <dot:TextBox Text="{value: Number2}" />
</p>
<p>
  <dot:Button Text="Calculate" Click="{command: Calculate()}" />
</p>
<p>
  The result is: {{value: Result}}
```

El framework se encarga de todo, y cada que en la vista cambie un valor "bindeado", se actualiza en el viewmodel también, y viceversa.

Blazor: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/03/22/get-started-building-net-web-apps-in-the-browser-with-blazor/

DotVVM: https://www.dotvvm.com